Facebook Reels upload with Api Trow error (#200) Subject does not have permission to post videos on this target
I need to upload facebook reels with api but show this error
{
"error": {
"message": "(#200) Subject does not have permission to post videos on this target",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 200,
"fbtrace_id": "A0vPpH6U1wfZ9o_4cMqmEH3"
}
}
I have done everything as per documentation all permissions are given eg
pages_show_list
pages_read_engagement
pages_manage_posts
and also i have page admin access (full control )
show some reference image 

Notice how in all those requests in the documentation, it says Your_page_access_token ...? Your screenshot appears to show, assuming the token used in the request is the same as the one in the Graph API Explorer beneath, that you used your user access token.

If I'm not wrong when you're working with Reels and you want to post them on your Facebook Page you need a special token. I mean, a token for your page with the proper permissions.
I answer like that because I had the same error and then a colleague realiced that I was trying to do all the steps with the same token of the instagram API and another token of the Facebook account. That's why I got the error, the Facebook account token isn't the same token of the Facebook Page token.
I hope it helps a little, gl!
